# Convert text into db object and field identifier

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, analysis

Given a select statement that lists all my tables and columns, how do I convert the table and column names into identifiers that can be used in a seperate select statement?

In other words, if I have the string @Table = 'Person' and @Column = 'Name', I want something like this:

```
select 
    DATALENGTH(MAX(t.@Column)) as Longest, 
    DATALENGTH(MIN(t.@Column)) as Shortest 
from @Table as t;
```

Of course that does not accomplish what I want.  I want to know the length of the longest and shortest string stored in a column.  If I wanted this information for a single column, there would be no need to use these stringified-variables.  But I want to do this for every (varchar) column across my database.  Life is too short to create every SQL statement to accomplish this.  This is why I want a parametric mechanism for specifying the table and column.  How do I fix this to achieve the goal?

Of course I could be going about this all wrong.  Perhaps I should address each column by index, and convert to a column name only when output is needed.  Thoughts?

Comment: Only way to achieve this is by using dynamic sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(999)
DECLARE @col VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(50)

SET @col = <colname>
SET @table = <tablename>

SET @SQL = '
select 
DATALENGTH(MAX(t.@Column)) as Longest, 
DATALENGTH(MIN(t.@Column)) as Shortest 
from @Table as t'

SET @SQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQL, '@Column', @col), '@Table', @table)

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: It's really important to add some sort of disclosure or caveat for things like this when you give new users Dynamic SQL...It can lead to all kinds of issues they aren't prepared to handle.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this forum and not used to explain my sql. But I agree that dynamic sql + new users has risks. Here however the user already knew the basic syntax, so it was just a case of adding a few extra lines in a notepad.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to tsql and specifically dynamic sql this is a good read on things you should consider.  Most people, when they discover dynamic sql think of all kinds of uses and things they can do with it.  But like I said... take caution.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html